# How is the height of an element in html determined if it has no height value in CSS?

Tags: css

As far as I know the 'height' property in CSS is not inherited by default, so how is the height of an element determined when it is not specified?

Comment: By the content inside it?

Comment: For block elements: By its content. For inline elements: By its content, or by the line height.

Comment: @connexo it may sounds strange but it's the opposite, for block element, it's the line-height that will dictate the height and for inline element, it's the content and line-height will not affect their height.